# Determining flux through a paraboloid.

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

I am a bit confused about how to solve this exercise. I can't use Stokes Theorem since both sides are open right?

---

Let S be the surface of the paraboloid:        $ z=3-x^2-y^2 $ for $-1\leq z\leq 1$
oriented with the outward unit normal. Let

$\vec F(x,y,z)=x\vec i+z\vec j-y\vec k $ be the velocity field of the fluid

Answer (score 0):

The paraboloid is $x^2 + y^2 = 3-z$, so you always must have $z\leq 3$ (the vertex is at $z=3$).

So I wonder if you can do something like $$\int_{z\in[-1,1]} = \int_{z\in[-1,3]} - \int_{z\in[1,3]}$$

so that in the two integral on the RHS the boundary is connected?